# How to stream Stored videos on red5?

Tags: video-streaming, live, red5

I'm able to LIVE Stream on red5 using Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder but I want to run stored videos as well on red5. Is it possible using FMLE or directly from the server. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can play the stored videos as well,but they have to be in the flv format.And to convert any video to the flv format you can use FFMpeg http://ffmpeg.org/
If you need any more help,you can ask me.Cheers